# Meaning of jQuery's first 5 lines of code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind of interested to find out how the jQuery code works, but the moment I opened the jQuery file, I stumbled upon this:

```
! function(a, b) {
    "object" == typeof module && "object" == typeof module.exports ?
    module.exports = a.document ? b(a, !0) : function(a) {
        if (!a.document) throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");
        return b(a)
    } : b(a)
}("undefined" != typeof window ? window : this, function(a, b) {
/*contains the rest of the code */
});
```

This syntax is unlike anything I've ever seen or it's just too complicated and vast to find out. I've searched the entire Google, but I found no related result. What does it mean?

More specifically:

- What does this code serve?
- Why are two `?` operators used consecutively without a `:` in between? (lines 2, 3)
- What's the purpose of the `!` operator before the function in the first line and why it's also used before `0` in line 3? If `0` is `false`, does `!0` mean `true`?

Comment: `condition ? expre1 : expre2` its called [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: I know the ternary operator. In the 2nd line after `module.exports ?` follows another `?`.

Comment: I believe u should check an uncompressed one. All u want to know is well commented: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js

Comment: Thanks @MMhunter. I couldn't find a commented one and I uncompressed a minified one myself. Is there a commented 2.2.4 version?

Comment: o yes u can just find them all on the jQuery CDN https://code.jquery.com/.

Comment: Oh, great I just found a 3.0.0 version. Thanks @MMhunter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried to open the distribution file of jQuery, you've probably found minified and obfuscated code, beyond readability. You might be better off if you tried to learn from the source code on [Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery), more specifically, the snippet you posted, seems to be [this](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/wrapper.js) file. It's all nicely commented

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @Rando. I thought it was just me who couldn't read that code.